# Alert the user to open application in IE or fire fox browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When ever user tries to open an application  other  than   **mozilla(fire fox) or  IE**  browser , we  need to alert the user telling him please open the application in  IE or Firefox browser. And the browser  which he  has  opened  the  application  should  stop  and  we  should not  close the  browser in which he  has  opened
Ex : like  other  browser ( google  crome, opera )

So  first  I need  to  check which  browser are  they  running the  application based on that I need to  send  an alert message.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: By application you mean a web page?

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively sure that your app will not work in other browsers? Blocking specific browsers is so 1998 - could you solve it with "your browser is not supported, countinue at your own risk"? Also, not all browsers using the Gecko renderer identify as "Firefox" - although that's the most common one. See e.g. this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html

Comment: The question may not be a good idea, but why the downvotes? Is it a duplicate? Is it unclear?  This question should not be downvoted. +1 from me to help offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use javascript navigator object to check browser and then alert user..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 document.write("Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName);
 document.write("<br /><br />");
 document.write("Browser Name: " + navigator.appName);
 document.write("<br /><br />");
 document.write("Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion);
 document.write("Platform: " + navigator.platform);
 document.write("<br /><br />");
 document.write("User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot do this**

Anything you rely on will be supplied by the browser and you *cannot trust this*.

Anyone can manipulate their browser to lie about who they are, check out [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/) in firefox

Best sort your site out so that it supports multiple browsers...

Answer (score 0):

Check HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is the condition to use:

```
<script>
if ((navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") &&
    (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4)) {
} else if (window.sidebar) {
} else {
    alert("Please open the site in IE or Firefox");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What a weird combination of user agent string sniffing for one browser and assuming that a particular feature will be available only on a different specific browser.